# SonarQube shows issue closed but issue still persists

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

SonarQube server automatically labeled issues as closed but viewing a particular analyzed java file shows that the issue is still present in the code base as seen on SonarQube server. There is a separate environment that does have the change. The commonality is the local workstation, eclipse, and ant. The code base is independent and their are separate instances of SonarQube, Bamboo and Bitbucket. There are separate eclipse workspaces,, separate eclipse projects and separate sonar working files within the projects.

The analysis from one code base is apparently be used for analysis of another code base. The push upstream (to another SonarQube instance) shows "closed" for artifacts. Could the switching of SonarLint connections from the two servers in eclipse have caused this issue? Are status of issues downloaded in SonarLint then used to support SonarQube analysis?

Please provide some assistance with how the local environment maintains an analysis of a code base.

Comment: You question is not very clear. Did you check if you use the correct SonarQube instance? One option is to start over again by using an other project key or remove the current project (this is an admin action).

Comment: @JeroenHeier I simplified the description. I can always start over. I want to understand actions that should not be performed to keep an environment, like production, pristine.